# how can I repeat monadic instructions inside kind's monads?

Tags: functional-programming, monads, kind

I know that I can run monadic instructions sequentially inside monads in [Kind](https://github.com/uwu-tech/Kind) language, like this:

```
Test: _
  IO {
   IO.print(Nat.show(2))
   IO.print(Nat.show(3))
   IO.print(Nat.show(4))
  }
```

```
output:
2
3
4
```

But is it possible to run monadic instructions repeatedly, like this below?

```
Test: _
  a = [2,1,3,4,5]
  IO {
    for num in a:
      IO.print(Nat.show(num))
  }
```

If it is possible how can I do it correctly?

Comment: I don't know kind, but does it provide recursion?

Comment: @Bergi yes it does, it is a functional "proofgramming" language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monads are usually represented by only two operators :

```
  return :: a -> m(a) // that encapulapse the value inside a effectful monad
  >>= :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
  // the monadic laws are omitted
```

Notice, the bind operator is naturally recursive, once it can compose two monads or even discard the value of one and the return can be thought of as a "base case".

```
m >>= (\a -> ... >>= (\b -> ~ i have a and b, compose or discard? ~) >>= fixpoint)
```

You just have to produce that sequence, which is pretty straightforward. For example, in Kind we represent monads as a pair which takes a type-for-type value and encapluse a polymorphic type.

```
type Monad <M: Type -> Type> {
  new(
    bind: <A: Type, B: Type> M<A> -> (A -> M<B>) -> M<B>
    pure: <A: Type> A -> M<A>
  )
}
```

In your example, we just have to trigger the effect and discard the value, a recursive definition is enough :

```
action (x : List<String>): IO(Unit)
  case x {
    nil : IO.end!(Unit.new) // base case but we are not worried about values here, just the effects
    cons : IO {
      IO.print(x.head) // print and discard the value
      action(x.tail) // fixpoint
    }
  }

test : IO(Unit)
  IO {
    let ls = ["2", "1", "3", "4", "5"]
    action(ls)
  }
```

The IO as you know it will be desugared by a sequence of binds!
Normally in case of list it can be generalized like the mapM function of haskell library :

```
Monadic.forM(A : Type -> Type, B : Type,
  C : Type, m : Monad<A>, b : A(C), f : B -> A(C), x : List<A(B)>): A(C)
  case x {
    nil : b
    cons : 
      open m
      let k = App.Kaelin.App.mapM!!!(m, b, f, x.tail)
      let ac = m.bind!!(x.head, f)
      m.bind!!(ac, (c) k) // the >> operator
  }
```

It naturally discard the value and finally we can do it :

```
action2 (ls : List<String>): IO(Unit)
  let ls = [IO.end!(2), IO.end!(1), IO.end!(3), IO.end!(4), IO.end!(5)]
  Monadic.forM!!!(IO.monad, IO.end!(Unit.new), (b) IO.print(Nat.show(b)), ls)
```

So, action2 do the same thing of action, but in one line!.
When you need compose the values you can represent as monadic fold :

```
Monadic.foldM(A : Type -> Type, B : Type,
  C : Type, m : Monad<A>, b : A(C), f : B -> C -> A(C), x : List<A(B)>): A(C)
  case x {
    nil : b
    cons : 
      open m
      let k = Monadic.foldM!!!(m, b, f, x.tail)
      m.bind!!(x.head, (b) m.bind!!(k, (c) f(b, c)))
  }
```

For example, suppose that you want to sum a sequence of numbers that you ask for the user in a loop, you just have to call foldM and compose with a simple function :

```
Monad.action3 : IO(Nat)
  let ls = [IO.get_line, IO.get_line, IO.get_line]
  Monadic.foldM!!!(IO.monad, IO.end!(0), 
      (b, c) IO {
        IO.end!(Nat.add(Nat.read(b), c))
      },
   ls)

test : IO(Unit)
  IO {
    get total = action3 
    IO.print(Nat.show(total))
  }
```

For now, Kind do not support typeclass so it make the things a little more verbose, but i think a new support to forM loops syntax can be thought in the future. We hope so :)

Comment: Thanks for this very complete answer! It would be nice to have this `foldM` and `forM`, (and maybe a syntax for `forM`) in the base directory.